# How to get "standard" full account privileges on new account? [16.0.4 Server]

Tags: 16.04, server, permissions, ssh, virtualbox

I cloned a VM and changed its hostname and the sole account name as part of changing it from the source it was cloned from. However, the modified account behaves differently to the original.

It seems like its privileges are different?

When I `ssh` into the original system and the clone the terminals are different:
[image: screenshot]

And using `nano` shows a warning message on the cloned version of the OS:

```
Unable to create directory /home/modelnode1/.nano: Permission denied
It is required for saving/loading search history or cursor positions.

Press Enter to continue
```

Requiring `sudo nano` to get rid of this.

Running `ls -lsa /home/modelnode1` returns:

```
total 8
4 dr-x------ 2 modelnode1 masternode 4096 Feb 28 15:06 .
4 drwxr-xr-x 5 root       root       4096 Feb 28 22:38 ..
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 modelnode1 masternode   56 Feb 28 15:06 Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.desktop
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 modelnode1 masternode   36 Feb 28 15:06 .ecryptfs -> /home/.ecryptfs/masternode/.ecryptfs
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 modelnode1 masternode   35 Feb 28 15:06 .Private -> /home/.ecryptfs/masternode/.Private
0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 modelnode1 masternode   52 Feb 28 15:06 README.txt -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.txt
```

Have I missed something when setting up this account?

**Any help is much appreciated!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the info you provided:

- You changed the username
- `Unable to create directory /home/modelnode1/.nano: Permission denied`

I suspect that the source of the problem, is in-complete change of user-name

Can you please confirm that the folder `/home/modelnode1/`

1. exists
2. Is owned by the new user-name `modelnode1`
3. Has read/write permissions to the owner of the directory

You can check it using the following command, which will show the directory owner and permissions:

```
ls -lsa /home/modelnode1/
```

The following commands might solve your problem:

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/modelnode1
sudo chown -R  modelnode1 /home/modelnode1
sudo chmod -R  711 /home/modelnode1
```

- `mkdir -p` command - will create the directory if it isn't exists yet
- `chown -R` command will change the owner of `/home/modelnode1` to be `modelnode1` (which currently doesn't have write permissions to this folder)
- `chmod -R` command will provide full permission to the owner of the folder

Comment: I've added the outputs from `ls -lsa /home/modelnode1` to the original question. Is that this issue do you think? Thanks.

Comment: The "." directory permission doesn't include write permission (it should have "drwxr-.....") running `sudo chmod 711 /home/modelnode1` should solve this issue

Comment: That's fixed the nano problem, thanks. Any idea about the terminal colour change?

Comment: I'm happy to hear that it fixed the permission problem. It is possible that the terminal color is defined in a file which was owned by the original user, and the current user didn't have read permission, hence it didn't use it. the `chown -R` with `chmod -R` command might solve it (you'll need to logout/login in order to see if it fixed it by any chance

Comment: Don't suppose you know where those files are located? Thanks.

Comment: perform `ls -lsa` in /home/modelnode1 and check files which start with `dot`, e.g. `.profile` , `.bashrc` - the color setting might be done there. those files should be owned by `modelnode1` (the new username)